# Weird Indexing problem in NumPy consuming too much memory

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I am just learning indexing in NumPy and I am seeing these weird indexing issues with NumPy arrays. Here for instance, when I try to index this simple 1_D array;

```
import numpy as np


arr = np.ndarray([5, 4, 10, 20, 25, 81, 9, 7])
print(arr[2])
```

I get the following weird output

```
[[[[[[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
      [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
      [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
      ...
      [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
      [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
      [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]

     [[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
      [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
      [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
```

with tons and tons of zero matrices. And when I index a slightly bigger array, it gives me this problem;

```
numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 229. PiB for an array with shape (5, 4, 10, 20, 25, 81, 9, 7, 914, 23, 5, 7, 86) and data type float64
```

Why is NumPy behaving so weirdly and consuming so much memory just of a simple 1_D array and unable to perform indexing properly? For the IDE, I am using IntelliJ with a Conda venv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using [`np.ndarray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html), when you probably meant to use [`np.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html).

What you're doing here is creating an 8-dimensional array of `5 * 4 * 10 * 20 * 25 * 81 * 9 * 7` elements.